# Mathematical notation for $i^{th}$ canonical basis vector for the n-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

One of my constraints in an optimization problem involves using canonical basis vector for the n-dimensional space.

How do I precisely write $j^{th}$ canonical basis vector for the n-dimensional space as a vector.

Normally its like

$n\times 1$ vector $\mathbf{e}_j$ is

\begin{gather*}
\mathbf{e}_j=\begin{cases}
  1 & \text{, } i=j\\    
  0 & \text{, } i\neq j\\   
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

and $1\leq j\leq n$.

Comment: You are probably talking about $\mathbb{R}^n$ or at most some other vector space which elements are tuples of scalars. Note that in an arbitrary $n$-dimensional vector space, there doesn't need to be a basis to single out and call the canonical basis. For example, a plane with one point marked as $0$ is a vector space for addition defined by the parallelogram construction and multiplication by scalars by homotheties with respect to $0$. But there is no special pair of points (not collinear with $0$) to call canonical.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you’ve already written basically suffices, but to be a bit clearer you could say:

Assuming you’re working in the real numbers...

The $j^{th}$ canonical basis vector $\mathbf{e}_j$ = $\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $a_i = 1$ if $i = j$ and $0$ otherwise.